# C# datatable add method from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm using .net 3.5 datatable and add rows to a datatable from more than one thread. when not usin lock I get mismatch between the datatablr rows count and the maximum index. When trying to serialize the table i get an exception `there is no rows at poitions X`. of course I can lock the datatable but I would like to know what is the cause. I would expect the `row.count()` method to return base on the row maxmimum index +1 and not the have a non independed counter. also, where can I find the internal implementation of `rows.Add` (params) method? it seems like the counter goes up per adding even if in soem cases the adding is on the same row.

**Edit:** thanks for the comments. I do know it is not thread safe for write and already solve it by using lock on the syncroot object. I would like to see what happen internally in the add method to see where the count get messed up.

Comment: citation from DataTable docs : This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Post your example code so we can try and replicate the problem.

Comment: you could easy reproduce it:
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                new Thread(()=> dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {})).Start();
            }

now check the count value and the list of row. they are not equals.

Comment: @AntonioBakula, if I could +1 that comment a million times I would. One very common mistake in programming is assuming that multi-threading is just fully encapsulated and you don't have to worry about it. It's almost as big a mistake as people thinking because there is "garbage collection" in .NET they don't have to concern themselves with how they setup and scope their object references.

Answer (score 4):

The cause is simple: `DataTable` is not thread-safe. It makes no *claim* to be thread-safe (against competing writes), and it is not *required* to be thread-safe. Most code is ***not*** thread-safe, and unless something explicitly says "I'm thread-safe for the following scenarios", you should assume it isn't.

Most commonly, in this scenario, it means one of:

- an index update is getting lost, i.e. both are doing `count++` at the same time, at it goes up by only 1
- an operation results in crazy data when the array is being copied, grown, shrunk or rearranged

The fix is simple: if any thread is changing the table, it must have exclusive access. So synchronize. `lock` is the easiest option, but more exotic options like `ReaderWriterLockSlim` exist.

Then the next step would be to decide: do we *really* want to be using `DataTable`?

Comment: so the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class uses the basic `lock` but just has more elaborate surroundings that are encapsulated away from you?